# Add textbox to all slides in powerpoint 2016

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I inherited a 100+ slides powerpoint presentation and I need to add new text to every slide. There already is a footer text that needs to stay where it is.

Is it possible to add a textbox to all slides ? If not, is it possible to add more than 1 "footer text" ?

Comment: Does that box have to be the same across all slides? Or does the content have to change? Please specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using the Slide Master in PowerPoint 2016.

1. Open Slide Master View by opening the View tab on the Ribbon and then clicking the Slide Master button, found in the Presentation Views group.
2. Make any formatting changes that you want (add a textbox in this example)

[image]

3. Click the Normal View button near the bottom right of the window to return to Normal View.